# How to create new columns in a data frame from a columns that has a vector?

Tags: pyspark, pickle

I'm trying to create a few news columns in a data frame from an already existing column that has a vector or 10 float values. If I use a udf, I'm getting a "**Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o90.__getstate__**" error

I'm creating a spark instance and running the operation in it.

**Part 1:** (Just creating a sample data frame)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lower, udf, lit, substring
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType


data = [([0.15338473676518236,0.11111990827514251,0.1094681573180615,0.08678457544315374,0.08565640776751143,0.08284697154989813,0.08199811585174373,0.07326450301060178,0.0660288568201205,0.0569631751252344,0.04420535033355498,0.02915343747658533,0.019125804263209503],)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['probability'])

df = df.withColumn('ModelVersion', lit('1.0.1'))
df = df.withColumn('loannumber', lit('123456'))
df = df.withColumn('callstartdatetime', lit('2018-10-13 13:21:37'))

new_df = df.select('loannumber', 'ModelVersion', 'probability','callstartdatetime' )
new_df.show()
```

**Output**:

```
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|loannumber|ModelVersion|probability                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |callstartdatetime  |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|123456    |1.0.1       |[0.15338473676518236, 0.11111990827514251, 0.1094681573180615, 0.08678457544315374, 0.08565640776751143, 0.08284697154989813, 0.08199811585174373, 0.07326450301060178, 0.0660288568201205, 0.0569631751252344, 0.04420535033355498, 0.02915343747658533, 0.019125804263209503]|2018-10-13 13:21:37|
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

**Part 2:**

```
def get_by_index(v, index):
    return str(v[index])

get_by_index_udf = udf(get_by_index, StringType())

data = new_df.select('loannumber',
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(0)).alias('probability_hour8'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(3)).alias('probability_hour9'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(1)).alias('probability_hour10'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(4)).alias('probability_hour11'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(2)).alias('probability_hour12'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(5)).alias('probability_hour13'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(6)).alias('probability_hour14'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(7)).alias('probability_hour15'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(8)).alias('probability_hour16'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(9)).alias('probability_hour17'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(10)).alias('probability_hour18'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(11)).alias('probability_hour19'),
                     get_by_index_udf('probability', lit(12)).alias('probability_hour20'))

data.show(10, False)
```

**Error:**

````
  File "/data/yarn/local/usercache/svc-oozie-workflows/appcache/application_1563419829374_2193/container_e466_1563419829374_2193_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 235, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 409, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/data/yarn/local/usercache/svc-oozie-workflows/appcache/application_1563419829374_2193/container_e466_1563419829374_2193_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 652, in save_instancemethod
    self.save_reduce(types.MethodType, (obj.__func__, obj.__self__), obj=obj)
  File "/data/yarn/local/usercache/svc-oozie-workflows/appcache/application_1563419829374_2193/container_e466_1563419829374_2193_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 786, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 736, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/data/yarn/local/usercache/svc-oozie-workflows/appcache/application_1563419829374_2193/container_e466_1563419829374_2193_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 804, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/data/yarn/local/usercache/svc-oozie-workflows/appcache/application_1563419829374_2193/container_e466_1563419829374_2193_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 804, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 781, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 808, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/data/yarn/local/usercache/svc-oozie-workflows/appcache/application_1563419829374_2193/container_e466_1563419829374_2193_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 804, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 781, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 805, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 521, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/data/yarn/local/usercache/svc-oozie-workflows/appcache/application_1563419829374_2193/container_e466_1563419829374_2193_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 804, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 476, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 821, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 847, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/ds_env_v1.0/lib/python3.6/pickle.py", line 496, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/data/yarn/local/usercache/svc-oozie-workflows/appcache/application_1563419829374_2193/container_e466_1563419829374_2193_01_000001/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/data/yarn/local/usercache/svc-oozie-workflows/appcache/application_1563419829374_2193/container_e466_1563419829374_2193_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/data/yarn/local/usercache/svc-oozie-workflows/appcache/application_1563419829374_2193/container_e466_1563419829374_2193_01_000001/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 324, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name, value))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o90.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
exception in __main__
Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o90.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)```
````

Comment: I can't reproduce this is issue. Your code is running fine for me (Spark 2.4). Can you please check your code again?

Comment: I couldn't recreate the entire problem here because it was running on a framework. Putting the get_by_index() inside another function did the trick. Thanks for looking into though.